# Copy text from table row generate extra space for each <td> IE9

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-9, copy-paste

I'm having a auto adding space issue when copying text on simple table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar bar2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with a combination of meta tag below:

`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />`

Pasting text on copied text using IE10 browser with IE10 Browser Mode and IE9 Document standard mode resulted below:

```
foo bar bar2
```

Problem appears when I tried to paste text on copied text using IE9 browser with IE9 browser mode and IE9 Document standard mode with result below:

```
foo 

bar bar2
```

It is not possible for me to upgrade the PC using IE9 to IE10..
Any help would be greatly appreciated.